# Documenting enumeration in different page

Tags: c++, enums, doxygen

I've something like

```
/** This enumerator does this and that */
typedef enum {
  VALUE_1, //!< Use this value for this
  VALUE_2  //!< Use this value for that
} MyEnumeration;
```

This and that are long and detailed descriptions and I want to put them into separate page, in order to mantain little and readable the header file.

I've read about putting in separate page classes and global objects. From [this link](http://www.doxygen.nl/docblocks.html#structuralcommands) I've seen that I'm able to put description on other pages, but it spokes only about enumeration description, not single values.

How can I do it?

Comment: Btw, in C++ there's no need to use `typedef enum {} MyEnumeration`. Just use `enum MyEnumeration{};`

Comment: You're right. I'm documenting other people code in order to explain what I'm understood :) I'll try to change it.

Comment: Personally I think doxygen is a scaled down version of the devil: these days IDEs are pretty good at extracting comments when you need them. I much prefer properly documented headers and I find all the doxygen metatext obfuscating. Seems so contrived to change the **code** structure for the sake of documentation.

Comment: I don't want to change code structure. I wan to create a .dox page, or similiar, in order to explain what these enumerator values do. We need to provide html documentation for our libraries so it's a necessary step.

Comment: Did you have a look at \addtogroup and similar commands?

Comment: Yes but I did not find anything that can be used for my purpose. Maybe I must do some try in order to find right commands...